# Failing to itemize in a modified moderncv /cventry

Tags: itemize, moderncv

I'm getting this error when trying to `itemize` in a renewed `\cventry` in a `moderncv`:

```
Use of \@@array doesn't match its definition. \end{itemize}}
```

My modified `cventry` looks like this:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep}p{.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}%
        {\bfseries #2} & {\bfseries #3} \\%
        {\itshape #5} & {\itshape #4}\\%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
        {\end{tabular}}%
    {{} & {#7}\\\end{tabular}}%
\par\addvspace{#1}}
```

This is what I want to do:

```
\cventry{2016--2019}{Did this and that, including these tasks:%
    \begin{itemize}%
        \item 1;
        \item 2, with sub-items:
        \begin{itemize}%
            \item Sub-item (a)
            \item Sub-item (b)
        \end{itemize}
        \item item 3.
\end{itemize}}
}
```

I do callout `\usepackage{array}`.

I tried the alternatives proposed by @gonzalo-medina in this post: [Bulleted lists in moderncv cventry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13000/bulleted-lists-in-moderncv-cventry).

They didn't work for me. I keep on getting the same error. Maybe this happens as I am using a modified version of the `\cventry`?

---

### Update on @mensch request

Here the compilable snippet:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{banking}          
\moderncvcolor{blue}      
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
% Customization:
%\usepackage{fontspec}%Rendering must be done with XeLatex, not with PDFLatex.
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr} %Sets roman default font to Computer Modern
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array}
%This is @gonzalo-medina's suggestion:
\usepackage{enumitem}
%The following resets the way of cv entries:
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1ex}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep}p{.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}%
    {\bfseries #2} & {\bfseries #3} \\%
    {\itshape #5} & {\itshape #4}\\%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
    {\end{tabular}}%
{{} & {#7}\\\end{tabular}}%
\par\addvspace{#1}}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
% personal data
\name{Carl}{Sagan}
\title{\large \textbf{Populists Buster}}                 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}
}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}

\end{document}
```

I'm running it in the latest `moderncv`package available from its [CTAN repo here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: If I may ask, what is the purpose of your custom `cventry` with respect to the default one? why the default one does not fit your need?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mensch. I have updated accordingly.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin: I needed to change the alignment from the original one.

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious: have a look [at template.tex](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template.tex) at line 23: `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}` is not the alignment you are looking for. Am I right?

Comment: BTW, I get an error when I try to compile your MWE. I checked modenrcv version, and it's the same. Don't know if others got it to complile.
`! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 54.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
`

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin, partially yes. I wanted to have a measurement proportional to the paper size. I also wanted to change the alignment of word lines withing cells. The answer provided by @Mensch below helped to achieve that, including the use of `\items`within the entry description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a missunderstanding and a wrong code line, but let us do it step by step:

**1. Missunderstanding**

The Standard definition of command  `\cventry` is

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Only for the last parameter (`#7`) is a minipage used, allowing you to use `itemize` etc.

So for your used command `cventry` you have to end the tabular and print then inside a minipage argument 7 (`#7`):

```
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep}p{.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}%
    {\bfseries #2} & {\bfseries #3} \\%
    {\itshape #5} & {\itshape #4}\\%
    \end{tabular} % <===================================================
    \ifx&#7&%%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}% else <=============
    \fi
\par\addvspace{#1}}
```

**2. Code Error**

Your used code inside your command `\cventy`

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
{\end{tabular}}%
```

returns an error, use instead

```
\ifx&#7&%%
        \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}% else <=============
        \fi
```

I showed the corrected code here.

So with the following MWE (please see that I defined a new command `\mycventry` to be able to show the differece between original code `\cventry` of class `moderncv` and the new defined command `\mycventry` with your table and insereted list(s)):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{banking}          
\moderncvcolor{blue}      
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
% Customization:
%\usepackage{fontspec}%Rendering must be done with XeLatex, not with PDFLatex.
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr} %Sets roman default font to Computer Modern
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array}
%This is @gonzalo-medina's suggestion:
\usepackage{enumitem}
%The following resets the way of cv entries:
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1ex}

\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{% <==================================
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep}p{.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}%
    {\bfseries #2} & {\bfseries #3} \\%
    {\itshape #5} & {\itshape #4}\\%
    \end{tabular} % <===================================================
    \ifx&#7&%% <========================================================
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}%
    \fi
\par\addvspace{#1}}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
% personal data
\name{Carl}{Sagan}
\title{\large \textbf{Populists Buster}}                 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}
}
\mycventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2} % <==========
\mycventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}% <=============
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

you get the following pdf without error messages:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thanks @Mensch !
That worked as expected. The conditional I set was indeed problematic. Renewing the `\cventry` as shown below produces satisfactory results as well:
```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep}p{.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}%
 {\bfseries #2} & {\bfseries #3} \\%
 {\itshape #5} & {\itshape #4}\\%
 {#6} & {#7} \\%
 \end{tabular}%
\par\addvspace{#1}}
```